# Pass a result from multi-returing function to another one taking only one argument in Go

Tags: go

Is it possible to pass a result form function which returns multiple values directly to function which accepts only one? Example:

```
func MarshallCommandMap(mapToMarshall map[string]string) string {
    return string(json.Marshal(mapToMarshall))
}
```

The example above will cause compilation error:`multiple-value json.Marshal() in single-value context`. I know it is possible to get same result with additional variable:

```
func MarshallCommandMap(mapToMarshall map[string]string) string {
    marshaledBytes, marshalingError := json.Marshal(mapToMarshall)
    if (marshalingError != nil) {
        panic(marshalingError)
    }
    return string(marshaledBytes)
}
```

But is it possible to pass only first value direclty without any variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean doing something like python's tuple unpacking. 
Unfortunately this is not possible in Go (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, however 2 things with your code.

1. Shouldn't panic, either return an error or return an empty string.
2. You can make it shorter.

Example :

```
func MarshallCommandMap(mapToMarshall map[string]string) string {
    js, _ := json.Marshal(mapToMarshall) //ignore the error
    return string(js)
}
```

Comment: Panicing probably is appropriate in a case like this where Marshal should never return an error (with a `map[string]string` as input, it should have no trouble).  Silently eating the error seems worse.